# How to create opportunity Using Connected App Callback URL

Tags: apex, soql, api, c#, .net

I have used bellow URL to get opportunity list using SOQL Query in .net Web application :

token.instance_url +"/services/data/v33.0/query?q=SELECT+Id,Name+FROM+Opportunity"

In SQL Query we can write Insert,Update,Delete,Select Statement. But, SOQL Only Support Select Statement.

Can i create opportunity using URL like Above.?

Or Any other way to create opportunity using .net web application.

Answer (score 0):

What you mentioned is standard rest API for query the record. Similarly there are API to insert the record

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/dome_upsert.htm

You have to provide record data in Json format request with post method.